# display category name based on its equivalent id

Tags: options, theme-options, framework

I have a theme with options. I would like to display 3 posts for a specific woocommerce category, I could show category id and I don't know how to display products based on its category id, but I have code snippet it shows products by woocommerce category name. So I need now to a selected category name not its id, or to convert it from category id to category name?

I tried following but it did not work at all. Any help will be apreciated, I'm struggling with this 2 days.

```
$slidecat =theme_get_option('theme_slide_categories');
        $args = array( 
'post_type' => 'product', 
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'product_cat' => 'burger', 
'orderby' =>'date',
'order' => 'ASC' );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    the_title(); ?>
    
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

when I echo $slidecat it shows cat id of "burger" which is 16.

options area

```
$options[] = array( 'name' => __('Slider Category', 'theme'),
                'desc' => __('Select a category for the featured post slider', 'theme'),
                'id' => 'theme_slide_categories',
                'type' => 'select',
                'class' => 'hidden',
                'options' => $options_categories);
```

I hope code I've supplied here is enough to get help. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to convert it from category id to category name

> when I echo $slidecat it shows cat id of "burger" which is 16

You can use [`get_term_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_field/) to get the term/category slug by ID:

```php
// Get the slug and then pass it to WP_Query.
$cat_slug = get_term_field( 'slug', $slidecat, 'product_cat' );

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'product_cat'    => $cat_slug,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
);
```

Or you could actually just pass the category ID to `WP_Query` using the [taxonomy query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters), like so:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
//  'product_cat'    => 'burger', // don't set product_cat
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms'    => $slidecat,
            'field'    => 'term_id',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'ASC'
);
```

Additionally, you should replace the [`wp_reset_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/) in your code with [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) because the former is used only if the main WordPress query is modified (e.g. if you called [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) which should just be avoided).

Comment: Thanks Sally, your answer solved my problem, now I can display 3 woocommerce products based on a selected category. I'll accept your solution.